# Node.js exports a function as a variable or object between files

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

In moudle1.js, I am exporting a module as an object.

```
  module.exports = {

           attribute1: function(param1, param2) {
                   attribute2(param1);
                   attribute3(param2)
            }

           attribute2 : function(param) {
           }

           attribute3 : function(param1) {
           }
    };
```

In module2.js, I want to be able to

```
var module1 = require('./module1');

exports.module1 = module1.attribute1;
exports.module1 = module1.attribute2;
```

Notice that I did not write `module1.attribute1(param1,param2)` intentionally. I would like to not have to give parameters in this file, but in a third one I would be able to

```
var module2 = require('./module2');
var param1 = 'foo';
var param2 = 'dummy';
module.module1(param1,param2);
```

This is mainly for testing.

Comment: You can't refer to another property in the same object as `attribute2(param1);`.  That's just not how Javascript works.  You could refer to it as `this.attribute2(param1)` or you can name the parent object and refer to it by name.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually export the function itself, rather than an object.

Also, please don't use `function` as a *variable name*, this is a [reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words).

```
// function.js
module.exports = function (param1, param2) {...}
```

---

```
// module.js
var fn = require('./module');
fn('foo', 'dummy')
```

Comment: I edited the question. Is it the same case for multiple functions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `module1.js` which will be same as yours.

```
module.exports = {

           attribute1: function(param1, param2) {
                   attribute2(param1);
                   attribute3(param2)
            }

           attribute2 : function(param) {
           }

           attribute3 : function(param1) {
           }
    };
```

Create another file and name it `"index.js"`

Inside the file keep the content as

```
module.exports = {
     module1 : require('./module1').attribute1
     module2 : require('./module1').attribute2
     module3 : require('./module1').attribute3
}
```

Keep both the files in a single folder and name it for say `"module".`

export the folder name where you want to use the function

```
var module = require('./module')
```

and use the function

```
module.module1("foo""bar");
```